# Is there a certain number of used images allowed in Android Studio?

Tags: android

When I use a certain number of images in my android project, after running the emulator it stops working.
When the number of images I've used is minimized it works normally.

It's not due to faulty images because all of them work fine in another android project.
I don't know how to fix this, could be something wrong with my android, itself ? Please HELP

Comment: How do you use them ? What size are your images ? How are you loading them ? Please post LogCat / Stack trace when it crashes. Also try on real device.

Comment: I use then in an ImageView and every one of them work fine there are few number of images,, the max size of them is about 60MB ,, and I put them in the drawable (copy , past)

Comment: and for the LogCat and Stack trace ,, I don't know how to get them yet , I'm really new in android. I'll try to use a real device like you said , hope it works

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) for logCat and stack trace. 60mb may be too much, but try on a real device. Maybe edit your question and add your code, maybe I can see if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of emulator. Try to run and test your apps by using real devices.